# What does this sentence from a newspaper daily mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"We hope she is alive,"said her mother,Shanta Ben, the dark circles around her eyes giving her a haunted expression.

Does it mean that the dark circles around her eyes made her look haunted?

Comment: If you have a new question, ask it. Do not edit questions to invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. Dark circles around the eyes are often a symptom of long-term stress, especially lack of sleep, so their presence is associated with being haunted, or constantly worried.

Comment: So, "giving her a haunted expression",  "giving her a jovial expression" refers to the subject?

Comment: Yes, that's right.